# How to access Menu using Menuinflater

Tags: android

I am new to android and would like to create menu using menu inflater. To access menu on android emulator, one could simply press the menu button and menu would get displayed. However on a real device, how can I access the menu using menu inflater?
It probably sounds silly but like I said before, new to android.
The app's min. api level is 8.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working link for it :

http://androidcodejunction.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/ok/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuInflater exampleInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    exampleInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);

}
```

The "example_menu" being the name off the xml you have in the "menu" folder. Also there are many duplicates of this question.